# Replace a broken SLR mirror with a cut HDD?

Tags: film, repair, 35mm, mirror

I love film cameras and repairing them. 
However, I often encounter cameras with broken and scratched mirrors. 
Is it possible to use some old HDDs and cut them to replace those mirrors ? 
I want to find a good and inexpensive alternative to buying broken cameras and removing their mirrors...

Comment: Is it possible? Sure. Is it practical given your experience and resources? Probably not. (If it were, you wouldn't have had to ask.) Will the results be any good? Depends on your expectations. Would you care if you lose viewfinder brightness, TTL metering, etc?

Comment: What's an HDD ?

Comment: @Kahovius A good ol' "spinning rust" hard disk. Platters are made of highly polished glass.

Comment: @owl If we are talking about the mobile mirror, the HDD platter could be too heavy and strain the shutter mechanism.

Comment: _Can_ you cut an arbitrary shape? Have you tried? I don't know details of how those things are made, but they aren't exactly common window glass. I expect it's something more like the "Gorilla Glass" that's used for smart-phone screens. P.S., If you snap one in half, you will instantly be engulfed by a cloud of tiny sparkling flakes of whatever the metal coating is that they put on the glass—flakes small enough to hang in the air for several minutes. (Don't ask me how I know!!) It's probably not something you'll want to breathe.

Comment: Ahh, thanks @xenoid! Then I also think, for all the reasons so far mentioned, that this is not a good idea...

Comment: A scratched SLR mirror may not be much of a problem.  It should have no effect on the image formed on the film and likely relatively little on the viewfinder image.  A broken SLR mirror would be problematic as it is likely the mirror alignment and the frame it sits in could also be altered by whatever force broke the mirror.

Comment: I assume you will completele lose AF as the main mirror needs to be semi-transparent to allow AF sensor to get part of the light.